# Transform and remap an equirectangular image with a 90° roll

Tags: python, c, image, opencv

I have to **transform and remap an equirectangular image** to an other equirectangular image with a 90° roll.

I did it with [Pano2VR](http://ggnome.com/).

The problem is that I have to do it **programmatically from the server side**. So I can't use a G.U.I. to do it.

First, I oriented my research to *imagemagick*. I tried the [Fred ImageMagick scripts](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/) but could not find anyone to do what I want to do. Moreover, the processing time of an image appears very long compared to *Pano2VR*.

I directed my investigations to *OpenCV* and the [libgnomonic](https://www.github.com/FoxelSA/libgnomonic). It's presently the most interesting way. This library allows te user to transform projections (equirectangular to rectilinear and vice versa) or [make equirectangular mapping transformation](https://www.github.com/FoxelSA/libgnomonic/wiki/Equirectangular%20mapping%20transformation). I played with [Norama-suite](https://www.github.com/FoxelSA/norama-suite) wich contains some scripts to deal with the library. For example, I would to convert an rectilinear image to an equirectangular but **the output was just a black background image** (why ? I didn't find the answer).

However, this second link could resolve my problem. I have this image :

[image]

and I want to transform it to this image

[image]

Well, I'm not comfortable at all with C. 
I think I should use this two files :

- https://www.github.com/FoxelSA/libgnomonic/blob/master/src/gnomonic-transform.h
- https://www.github.com/FoxelSA/libgnomonic/blob/master/src/gnomonic-transform.c

But I don't know how. And above all, I want to understand.

Am I on the right way ? What transformation is applied on the first image ? Is there a way to do it with python or a bash script ?

Well, thank you for your help.

---

**EDIT Transposition of C in python **
The following code didn't work and return and IndexError.
However I tried to catch and pass the exception and the first right part of the image did not seem changed.

```
import math
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("img1.jpg")
img = img.convert('RGB')
pixel = img.load()
width, height = img.size

img2 = img.copy()
for y in xrange(height):
    for x in xrange(width):
        xx = 2*(y+0.5) / width - 1.0
        yy = 2*(y+0.5)/ height - 1.0
        lng = math.pi * xx
        lat = 0.5 * math.pi * yy

        # NOTE!  These axes are transposed because that's what the question is about
        Z = math.cos(lat) * math.cos(lng)  # normally X
        Y = math.cos(lat) * math.sin(lng)  # normally Y
        X = -math.sin(lat)                 # normally -Z
        D = math.sqrt(X*X+Y*Y)

        lat = math.atan2(Z, D)             # ? normally lat = math.asin(Z)
        lng = math.atan2(Y, X)

        #ix and iy must be integers
        ix = int((0.5 * lng / math.pi + 0.5) * width - 0.5)
        iy = int((lat/math.pi + 0.5) * height  - 0.5)

        #not sure of this part to remap the image
        newpixel = pixel[ix, iy]
        img2.putpixel([(x+width/4) % width, y], newpixel)
        #I tries as mentionned in the following code to invert x and y in the two previous lines but the index error out of range comes back 
img2.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

Your transformation has two steps. The first step is a transformation of the projection sphere, the second is the 90° roll.

A 90° roll of an equirectangular image is just a horizontal shift of a quarter of the image width. The first transformation is more complicated: You basically want to rotate the sphere so that the north pole is at latitude 0 and longitude 0 (somewhere in the Gulf of Guinea, if you take thze Earth as reference.)

You can go about this transformation with these steps;

- Translate the x and y position of each pixel into a longitude, −π ≤ long ≤ π, and a latitude, −π/2 ≤ lat ≤ π/2. This is a linear transformation.
- Create x, y, and z coordinates of the corresponding longitude and latitude on a unit sphere; positive z is the north pole.
- Rotate these Cartesian coordinates. In your case, you just have to swap some dimensions, but this could be a general transformation with any transformation matrix.
- Calculate the longituide and latitude of the rotated coordinates.
- Transform the new longitude and latitude to a pixel position.

Here's C code that works. (I know that you have tagged the question with Python, but the code below is mostly formulas that work similarly in python. You have to take care: All of the number are floating point numbers except the pixel indixes `x`, `y`, `ix`and `iy`. I would have done this in Python, but I have no experience with the Python Image Library.)

```
for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        double xx = 2 * (x + 0.5) / width - 1.0;
        double yy = 2 * (y + 0.5) / height - 1.0;
        double lng = pi * xx;
        double lat = 0.5 * pi * yy;

        double X, Y, Z;
        double D;
        int ix, iy;

        Z = cos(lat) * cos(lng);    // corresponds to original x
        Y = cos(lat) * sin(lng);    // corresponds to original y
        X = -sin(lat);              // corresponds to original z

        D = sqrt(X*X + Y*Y);        // distance in the XY plane
        lat = atan2(Z, D);
        lng = atan2(Y, X);

        ix = (0.5 * lng / pi + 0.5) * width - 0.5;
        iy = (lat / pi + 0.5) * height - 0.5;

        dest[y][(x + width / 4) % width] = src[iy][ix];
                                    // width/4 offset ist the 90° roll
                                    // % width wraps the longitude
    }
}
```

The quality of the resulting image is okay, but not as good as that of your reference image, especially near the poles. A better algorithm woul average and smoothze the colour values. The algorithm above just maps one destination pixel to a source pixel.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations. Well, I will try to implement your code in a python module. However, the result should be better and faster in C. I may try to use Cython.

Comment: Well, I did it but the result is bad. I think the last part of my code is not good.

Comment: At first glance: You haven't applied the modulus operator `%` to your `x` coordinate. That means that the x coordinates for the last quarter are out of range. Try using `img2.putpixel([(x + width/4) % width, y], newpixel)`.

Comment: Oh sorry. Well I corrected it but the error is still here. I commented my code because when I correct the last difference with your code, the out of range error comes back.

Comment: When I run your code (but without the PIL), I get valid indices for both source and destination pixels. It would be good to know the values of the pixel positions when the exception is thrown.